# How to create a MiniApps for Samsung Tablets?

Tags: android, galaxy, samsung-mobile

I noticed that samsung tablets have a button at the center of the system bar that opens a list of "mini-apps" (World Clock, Calculator, Music Player, etc). (I'm using one Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1)

Anyone knows what to do to create an application that can appear in that list? Some identification at the `AndroidManifest.xml`? Or if it is impossible to put an application that is not built-in at this list of miniapps?

Comment: Are they [widgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)? You could try installing a free widget from the Play Store and check whether it appears in the list of mini-apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.
Those apps are samsung specific.